# SQL Join to include NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to join 3 tables into a select statement but count the occurences of one while still showing the record if no occurences happen.

My example can be seen in the quick sqlFiddle that I've put together. I've tried to use left joins but it doesn't produce the result I want.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2840/8

This is the SQL Statement:

```
SELECT O.OptionID,O.OptionName, Count(A.OptionID) AS Total
FROM Options as O
    LEFT JOIN Answers AS A  ON O.OptionID = A.OptionID 
    LEFT JOIN Users as U ON A.UserId = U.UserID  
WHERE   A.QuestionID = 1
GROUP BY O.OptionID,O.OptionName
```

What I want it to return is all the rows from the options table and display a 0 in the total column if no answers were found for that option.

What the current fiddle returns:

[image: 1]

What I would like it to return:

[image: 2]

Comment: why has no-one pointed out that the Users is not needed?

Comment: You are correct, it isn't needed in this example, but I included it because on my real life problem, it is essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subselect answer:

```
SELECT O.OptionID,O.OptionName, Count(A.OptionID) AS Total
FROM Options as O
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT OPTIONID,USERID 
    FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = 1
) AS A  ON O.OptionID = A.OptionID 
LEFT JOIN Users as U ON A.UserId = U.UserID  
GROUP BY O.OptionID,O.OptionName
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a WHERE clause with LEFT JOIN, which is making it act like an INNER JOIN.

Try this:

```
SELECT O.OptionID, O.OptionName, Count(A.OptionID) AS Total
FROM Options as O
    LEFT JOIN Answers AS A  ON O.OptionID = A.OptionID 
    and A.QuestionID = 1
    LEFT JOIN Users as U ON A.UserId = U.UserID  
GROUP BY O.OptionID,O.OptionName
```

Comment: This does work but I have 200 million records in the answers table, the where clause is essential to have the index triggered. Doing it your way it doesn't actually load at all on the live database. How can I work around that? Thanks!

Comment: Use a subselect, replace `answers as A` with `(SELECT OPTIONID,USERID FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = 1) AS A`

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like below...

```
       SELECT O.OptionID,O.OptionName, Count(A.OptionID) AS Total
       FROM Options as O
       LEFT JOIN Answers AS A  ON O.OptionID = A.OptionID and A.questionId=1
       LEFT JOIN Users as U ON A.UserId = U.UserID  
       GROUP BY O.OptionID,O.OptionName
```

Answer (score 0):

Th Users table is not referenced, and this matches the expected result using the data at your sqlfiddle.

```
SELECT O.OptionID,O.OptionName, Count(A.OptionID) AS Total
FROM Options as O
    LEFT JOIN Answers AS A  ON O.OptionID = A.OptionID
                            AND A.QuestionID = 1
GROUP BY O.OptionID,O.OptionName
```

By the way: You do not gain any advantage by using a subquery. The added join condition does exactly the same job.

But you will gain an advantage by avoiding a redundant join.

Answer (score 0):

same as @mjsqu but will avoid subset. This is more better way of joining with out subsets

```
SELECT O.OptionID,O.OptionName, Count(A.OptionID) AS Total
FROM Options as O
    LEFT JOIN Answers AS A  ON O.OptionID = A.OptionID and A.QuestionID = 1
    LEFT JOIN Users as U ON A.UserId = U.UserID  
GROUP BY O.OptionID,O.OptionName
```